# Pagination from Nodejs Mongoose subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using mongoose-paginate-v2 I am trying to Paginate a subcomment called "**Items**" of a collection but I have not succeeded. This is my model:

```
    const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');

    const PettyCashItemsSchema = Schema (
    {
        pettyCashId:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'PettyCash',
            required: [true, 'La Caja Chica es Obligatoria']
        },
        user:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'Users',
            required: [true, 'El Usuario es obligatorio']
        },
        item: {
            type: Number,
            unique: true
        },    
        items:[{
            concept: {
                type: String,
                maxlength:50,
                required: [true, 'El Concepto es obligatorio']
            },
            incomeAmount:{
                type: Number,
                maxlength:50,
                default:0,
                required: [true, 'El Ingreso es obligatorio']
            },
            expenseAmount:{
                type: Number,
                maxlength:50,
                default:0,
                required: [true, 'El Egreso es obligatorio']
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                maxlength:50,
                required: [true, 'La Observación es obligatoria']
            },
            status: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true,
                required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
            }
        }],
        status: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
            required: [true, 'El Estatus es obligatorio']
        }
    }  
    );
```

And I am trying to do it in this way but it returns the entire document and not just the subdocument that I need paginated:

```
        const options = {
            lean: true,
            limit: 10,
            page: 1,
            read: {
              pref: 'secondary',
              items: [
                {
                    status: true,
                },
              ],
            },
          };
        
        let items = await PettyCashItems.paginate( { 'pettyCashId': pettyCashId }, options );
        
        res.json( items );
```

Until now I don't understand how to achieve it but I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if MongoDB provide a way to do this out of the box but you can use aggregation `$function` to achieve this.

```
PettyCashItems.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            pettyCashId: pettyCashId 
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            items: {
                $function: {
                    body: function(items) {
                        var skip = (page - 1) * limit
                        var to = skip + limit
                        return {
                            docs: items.slice(skip, to), 
                            totalDocs: items.length
                        }
                    },
                    args: ['$items'],
                    lang: 'js'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

and if you wanna paginate `PettyCashItems` too, you can add `$skip` and `$limit` stages before `$addFields` stage

Answer (score 0):

To add pagination to a sub-document using mongoose-paginate-v2, you need to add pagingOptions in your options and replace paginate with paginateSubdocs

```
const options = {
        pagingOptions: {
            populate: {
                path:'items',
                // you can add more options here like select, model, match
            },
            // additional options for what you are populating(in your case 'items')
            limit: 10,
            page: 1,
        },
      };
    
    let items = await PettyCashItems.paginateSubDocs( { 'pettyCashId': pettyCashId }, options );
```

Information is from mongoose [Query-populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) and [mongoose-paginate-v2 docs- Pagination for Sub-Documents section](https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2#readme)